# local copy of the transaction data in the local database of the consumer facing application

Tags: cloud

we have multiple consumer facing applications as the member engagement portals  and all these applications get the transaction data from on-premise mainframe system through enterprise API layer. And, we are working on to replicate onpremise mainframe service and the raw data into the Cloud database using CDC pipeline. We plan to expose new microservices on the cloud for all other consumers. But one of our consumers is enforcing  to subset of data view returned by the enterprise services into their local cloud datastore. The primary reasons to have the local copy of the data confirming to the application domain data model instead of making the real-time calls to the enterprise API. The primary reason is to reduced the latency with the data fetching to reduce the response time. is that very common implementation these days to  have the local copy of the transaction SOR data instead of making call to the APIs which are called by multiple other consumers.

We are just started the journey on this to move the on-premise data to the cloud.